# Find descendants of a specific node with Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

Say I have an xml document and want to get the "NodeID" and "Description" element out of each Node, without necessarily knowing whether they're a sub-element of some child, or just a child.

```
<Stuff>
    <data>
        <Nodes>
            <NodeID>1</NodeID>
            <Name>thingA</Name>
            <MoreInfo>
                <Description>Scooter</Description>
            </MoreInfo>
        </Nodes>
        <Nodes>
            <NodeID>2</NodeID>
            <Name>thingB</Name>
            <MoreInfo>
                <Description>Bike</Description>
            </MoreInfo>
        </Nodes>
    </data>
</Stuff>
```

So I'd ideally end up with: 1, Scooter; 2, Bike.

```
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("Nodes", resultXml, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodes.item(i);
    logger.info("Evaluating: " + node.toString());

    String nodeID = xpath.evaluate("//NodeID", node);
    String description = xpath.evaluate("//DescriptionID", node);

    System.out.println("Found: " + nodeID + ", " + description);
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Evaluating: <NodeID>1</NodeID><Name>thingA</Name><MoreInfo><Description>Scooter</Description></MoreInfo>
Found: 1, Scooter
Evaluating: <NodeID>2</NodeID><Name>thingB</Name><MoreInfo><Description>Bike</Description></MoreInfo>
Found: 1, Scooter
```

The node is correct, but it keeps "finding" things as if it were looking from the beginning of the xml document. How do I search just for decendents of the node in question? I would think that the node being the source of the evaluation would do the trick...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//NodeID` and `//Description` are *absolute* paths which will start searching from the root of the document that contains the context node.  The expressions in this case will match all nodes named `NodeID` (respectively `Description`) in the whole document, and when you evaluate such an expression as a string this will give you the string value of the first matching node in document order.

To look just within the context node itself you need to use *relative* paths by adding a leading dot, for example `.//NodeID`.